# How to disable responsiveness for tablet in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to disable bootstrap responsive only on tablet **or** to set a specific size for the display in px??

I want Bootstrap only responsive on mobile phones and desktop.

So, if the page is opened on the tablet, then the display appears as a desktop display.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 3, go into the variables.less file. Find:

```
@screen-md: 992px;
```

change it to:

```
 @screen-md: @screen-sm;
```

Compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use css `@media` queries. Read up about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Open up your `bootstrap.css` file. Now, do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and look for `@media` somewhere. It'll have the screen size as it's argument. You simply need to comment out the size corresponding to your tablet.

Comment: tried it, but still no fix, need to learn more about media query. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap's customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables) to achieve that.

Basically what you want is that the tablet layout is the same as the desktop layout. The way Bootstrap determines which version to display is with 4 variables: `@screen-xs-min`, `@screen-sm-min`, `@screen-md-min` and `@screen-lg-min` for extra small, small, medium and large.

Extra small is usually for phones, small for tablets, medium for small desktop screens (or large tablets) and large is for very large desktop screens. Note that this isn't a guarantee, it just uses more of your screen real estate when it's available.

So what you want is for the tablet break point `@screen-sm-min` to never occur, so you can just set its value to `0` (or `1`, I'm not sure `0` is an accepted value.

Alternatively, you could just remove all the CSS that's surrounded by a `@media` query for the width of the tablets.

I suggest you read more about [Bootstrap's responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), it's better to use them properly then just get rid of them.